# How to use following in Xpath to get siblings in a Tag

Tags: xpath

I have following  Structure: I am trying to build a robust method to extract the elements of FT1_19_0 of the FT1_19 Tag in the order they appear. However 
in my results the elements are rearranged. How can i get my result in correct order.

```
 //*/FT1_19/FT1_19_0[contains(../FT1_19_2,'I10') and 
 not(.=../following::FT1_19/FT1_19_0)]
The Result(Rearranged)
X50.0XXA
M76.891
M17.11
M23.303

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<root>
<FT1>
<FT1_1>1</FT1_1>
<FT1_4>20180920130000</FT1_4>
<FT1_5>20180924110101</FT1_5>
<FT1_6>CG</FT1_6>
<FT1_7>99203</FT1_7>
<FT1_9/>
<FT1_10>1.00</FT1_10>
<FT1_13>NPI</FT1_13>
<FT1_16>
  <FT1_16_1>Gavin, Matthew, MD</FT1_16_1>
  <FT1_16_3>22</FT1_16_3>
</FT1_16>
<FT1_19 NO="1">
  <FT1_19_0>M76.891</FT1_19_0>
  <FT1_19_2>I10</FT1_19_2>
</FT1_19>
<FT1_19 NO="2">
  <FT1_19_0>M17.11</FT1_19_0>
  <FT1_19_2>I10</FT1_19_2>
</FT1_19>
<FT1_19 NO="3">
  <FT1_19_0>M23.303</FT1_19_0>
  <FT1_19_2>I10</FT1_19_2>
</FT1_19>
<FT1_19 NO="4">
  <FT1_19_0>X50.0XXA</FT1_19_0>
  <FT1_19_2>I10</FT1_19_2>
</FT1_19>
</FT1>
</root>
```

Comment: After adding </FT1></root> to complete the XML structure, I was able to get the correct order using the xpath you provided. I used notepad++ to evaluate the expression. What are you using to evaluate the xpath?

Comment: Am also using Notepad++ but it seems to rearrange my results starting with the last value as shown in my question. Also tried with http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath and got the same result. Did you make any change to the Xpath statement?

Comment: I didn't change the xpath. Try this site https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html.

Comment: @Preston i finally did more research and found ot what i was doing wrong. i replaced it with //*/FT1_19/FT1_19_0[contains(../FT1_19_2,'I10') and 
 not(.=../preceding::FT1_19/FT1_19_0)] That was all it needed to get them in the right order

Answer (score 0):

Use this if you are using java:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ft1_19//following::ft1_19_0"));     
for(WebElement we:list) {
            System.out.println(we.getText());
        }
```